# Ionic React Native - There was an error with the request: /storage/emulated/0/Download/newPicture.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, react-native, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am facing issues with my Ionic React Android App. I want to download a file to the Public Downloads Folder of Android, but I am always getting this error:

```
Msg: error block ...  There was an error with the request: /storage/emulated/0/Download/newPicture.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I am using following code:

```
function download(name){
    AndroidPermissions.hasPermission(AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        .then(status => {
          if (status.hasPermission) {
            console.log("Has permission");
            performAndroidDownload(name);
          } 
          else {
            console.log("Request permission");
            AndroidPermissions.requestPermission(AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
              .then(status => {
                if(status.hasPermission) {
                  performAndroidDownload(name);
                }
              });
          }
        });
}

    function performAndroidDownload(name:string){
        const filePath = File.externalRootDirectory +"Download/"+ name; 
        console.log(filePath);
        HTTP.downloadFile("https://url.com/uploads/"+match.params.id+"/"+name, {}, {}, filePath).then(response => {
        // prints 200
        console.log('success block...', response);
        }).catch(err => {
        // prints 403
        console.log('error block ... ', err.status);
        // prints Permission denied
        console.log('error block ... ', err.error);
        });
    }
```

I also added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to my AndroidManifest.xml, but it didn´t help.

Tried the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission as well, but didn´t help.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using an Android 10 device? Requesting legacy external storage is only for such devices.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, I am using an Android 10 device. I learned that since Android 10 it is required to request permissions at runtime, so implemented it, but it is still not working...

Comment: Since Android M/6 already, you mean. You should be able to create a file in that Download folder. I see you are only requesting for READ permission. But what do you think you need to create/write a file? ;-)

Comment: @blackapps Yeah sure. I already tried using the Write Permission, but same behavior.

Comment: here you need to add permissions in android manifest file

Comment: @ManojKashyam ionic with capacitor already adds all permissions to the mainfest file, so the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are already in the mainfest file.

Comment: ok that's good @BenFaist Now you need to also request to write external storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the permission issue!

After requesting the permission like above, I needed to add following line:

```
AndroidPermissions.requestPermissions([AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

The whole solution is:

```
function download(name){
    AndroidPermissions.hasPermission(AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        .then(status => {
          if (status.hasPermission) {
            console.log("Has permission");
            performAndroidDownload(name);
          } 
          else {
            console.log("Request permission");
            AndroidPermissions.requestPermission(AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
              .then(status => {
                if(status.hasPermission) {
                  performAndroidDownload(name);
                }
              });
          }
        });
}

function performAndroidDownload(name:string){
    const filePath = File.externalRootDirectory + "Download/" + name; 
    AndroidPermissions.requestPermissions([AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,AndroidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]).then(e => {
      
      HTTP.downloadFile("https://url.com/uploads/"+match.params.id+"/"+name, {}, {}, filePath).then(response => {
        // prints 200
        console.log('success block...', JSON.stringify(response));
    
        }).catch(err => {
        // prints 403
        console.log('error block ... ', err.status);
        // prints Permission denied
        console.log('error block ... ', err.error);
        });
    });

  }
```